# Existence of NP problems with complexity intermediate between P and NP-hard

Tags: complexity-theory, reference-request, np, p-vs-np

Assuming P!=NP, there is a result that there are decision problems intermediate between P and NP-complete. That is, the class NP cannot be a union of two disjoint subsets: P and NP-complete.

I could never quite understand the proof of the above result. The proof I saw in a textbook was starting with the assumption that one can enumerate all P and NP-hard problems, and then proceeding with a construction of a function that didn't fit in either. However, this construction seemed a bit fishy to me; in particular, the assumption that one can start with enumerated set of problems in a particular class, the NP.

Could you refer me to a clear self-contained proof of the statement in the 1st paragraph? More generally, what would be a good reference for proofs of such results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result you're describing is called 'Ladner's Theorem.'  The Wikipedia article on '[NP-Intermediate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-intermediate)' is probably a good place to start - you can find references to Ladner's original paper there.

There's also an [extensive list](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/79/problems-between-p-and-npc/) of such problems on the cstheory Stackexchange.

For a couple of proofs of Ladner's Theorem, check out [this note](http://oldblog.computationalcomplexity.org/media/ladner.pdf) adapted from Downy & Fortnow's paper '[Uniformly Hard Languages](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~fortnow/papers/uniform.pdf)'.