# What are the implications of P=NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, proof-techniques, np, polynomial-time, p-vs-np

Is there a list of implications of $P=NP$?

Presumably, a proof of $P \ne NP$ will be by contradiction, for which a list of consequences of $P=NP$ would be useful.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem#P_.3D_NP, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem#Polynomial-time_algorithms

Comment: @Juho I was looking for mathematical implications.

Answer (score 2):

There wouldn't be a lot of practical implications. In practice, the question is not whether a problem can be solved in polynomial time, the question is whether it can be solved in a reasonable amount of time.

Let's say I can solve the Travelling Salesman problem for n cities in n^12 nanoseconds. So what? N=50 still takes thousands of years.

No fast algorithms for this problem are known. P=NP doesn't magically give us any fast algorithms.

Of course P = NP would affect a huge number of open problems in computer science, where certain problems are obviously in P, and obviously in NP but not known to be NP-complete, and it is unknown where exactly between P and NP they are - all these problems would be known to be in P. (See this question for example: [Existence of NP problems with complexity intermediate between P and NP-hard](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19543/existence-of-np-problems-with-complexity-intermediate-between-p-and-np-hard?rq=1) )

And if a guaranteed polynomial time algorithm for checking primality hadn't been known, we would know that one exists (but that knowledge would have been no help whatsoever to find this algorithm).

Comment: "There wouldn't be a lot of practical implications." There _might not be_ a lot of practical implications. It's possible that P=NP, that the proof is nonconstructive and the best algorithm for TSP runs in time $\Theta(n^{12})$. It's also possible that we prove that P=NP precisely by finding an $O(n\log n)$ algorithm for SAT or TSP or something like that. Without knowing _why_ P=NP, we can't say what practical implications that would have.

Answer (score 1):

If P=NP, then all of the NP problems can be solved deterministically in Polynomial time.

This is because the NP problems are all essentially *the same problem*, just stated in different terms.

As far as lists go -- many of the NP-Complete problems are enumerated here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NP-complete_problems

Further implications? Our cryptosystems break down, armchair philosophers argue about what it means, the world changes, and somebody gets a Fields medal or Turing award + a big hunk of cash, etc... but that's a tangent.

For example, one of the classic NP problems is [clique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem). If you could solve clique with a polynomial time algorithm, this would prove that P=NP, and then you could also use your method for solving clique to solve all of the other problems on that wiki-list, as an implication.

Comment: If P=NP then all NP problems can be solved deterministically in polynomial time because you've just said that they're in P and that's what P means. It has nothing to do with "the NP problems are essentially the same problem." It would make sense to say "If there is a deterministic polytime solution for any NP-compete problem, then P=NP because all problems in NP are essentially the same problem."

Answer (score -2):

It also implies that some unsolvable problems may just be very hard.
One of which being "which specific genes cause the phenomenon of consciousness" which could yet be solvable.

Comment: No. P=NP would only have implications for which solvable problems can be solved efficiently. It wouldn't make unsolvable (undecidable) problems solvable: we know unconditionally that they can't be solved.