# Examples of problems in NP but not in P which we haven't proved NP complete

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np

If we find a problem we know for sure is in NP but not in NP-complete or P, we'll have proved P!=NP. One approach then is to identify problems in NP (but not P) we haven't been able to show to be NP-complete so far and try to prove they aren't in that set. Any examples of such problems? Preferably one problem per answer?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/19543/755, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/20930/5038

Answer (score 2):

The language constructed in the proof of [Ladner's Theorem](https://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/%7Erogaway/classes/220/winter06/ladner-theorem.pdf).

See also the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-intermediate) on the NP-intermediate class, which contains a list of problems that might be in NP-intermediate.